# Ubuntu Dock Shaking

Tags: boot, 20.04, 22.04

My Screen Dock is blinking like the one below. What can be the reason for this?
I have updated and upgraded my OS.
[image: Link to picture])

Comment: Please edit your question and correct the tags - you tagged multiple Ubuntu versions, including two EOL ones. Please mention only the Ubuntu release you are really using.